# On IIS cannot find existing application pool showed in CA

Tags: user-profile-service, iis, service-applications

We are using SP2010 on-premise Enterprise edition. It is a single server containing SQL2008 (not express) and SharePoint

Recently we found the User Profile Service application is not working. In the CA > User Profile Service Application it shows "This User Profile Application's connection is currently not available. The Application Pool or User Profile Service may not have been started. Please contact your administrator"

I clicked on Manage Service Application > select User Profile Service Application > Property. It is using an application pool that not existing in IIS. In the dropdownmenu all the pools' name are not existing in IIS. Check with PowerShell Get-SPServiceApplicationPool, it shows the same pools as dropdownmenu.  So I choose to create a new pool. It return success message but in IIS no new pool is create! Also the UPSA still returning the same error.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Interesting issue, but regardless of the the root cause (maybe someone deleted the app pool by mistake) you will be better off to rebuild/restore the UPS check the guidelines from MS: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg985419(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: @MarekSarad I have already recreate UPS. In the procedure to choose application pool or create a new pool, I get the same thing as mentioned above.

Comment: that is quite strange, you wrote that 'In the dropdownmenu all the pools' name are not existing in IIS' not sure do I understand it correctly, you don't see any applications pools in IIS manger that you see in Sharepoint? What version of WindowsServer are you running and do you open correct IIS manager (in WS2008 there were 2 available). In this kind of strange issues I usually run ULS viewer with show errors only and process explorer to nail down the issue.

Comment: It is win2008 server. I also feel strange. It looks like there are 2 IIS instance on the same server. The CA & web application are using IIS instance A and the service applications are using IIS instance B.

Comment: :) ok that is quite exotic configuration i have never stumbled upon. And according to this thread it is not possible http://serverfault.com/questions/536428/is-it-possible-to-run-multiple-instances-of-iis-7-5-on-the-same-server

Comment: Tried New-SPServiceApplicationPool cmdlet and new pool show up in dropdownmenu... but not in IIS manager.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The details steps here :

1. Open SharePoint Management Shell as Administrator.
2. Type this command

   ```
   Get-SPServiceApplicationPool | select Id, Name
   ```
3. Open IIS Manager > Application Pool > Match Application Pool GUID with the command result.

[image]

Refer [Get the corresponding SharePoint services name of the Application Pool Guid](https://mohamedelkassas.wordpress.com/2016/04/18/get-the-corresponding-sharepoint-services-name-of-the-application-pool-guid/)

Comment: For the issue that mentioned on your Quest, please check  [This User Profile Application’s connection is currently not available](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/user-profile-error/)

Answer (score 0):

I am so stupid. I forgot in SP2010, application pools created by CA or PowerShell are named with GUID. Hence when I open IIS manager I cannot find the new pools I created because they are named (e.g. 7caf285b-df15-91fgf-95a8-ca74edbddc01)

Refer to this old [post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/109441/app-pool-created-with-powershell-name-appears-as-guid-in-iis), I use `Get-SPServiceApplicationPool | select Id, Name` to get the GUID of pools and match the names.